# Non-dogmatic approach to REST -- maintaining session for authentication

Tags: rest, glassfish, jersey

I am designing my app which will have the standard web and Android front-end components that both access data via a RESTful API.  I plan to use Glassfish and Jersey for serving REST.

Where I am stuck, philosophically, is the REST spec's approach of not maintaining any session data, which requires authentication credential submission every single request.  What I am trying to do is to amalgamate the standard web app concept of session to my REST services such as:

1. User submits a request
2. SessionID from their browser is validated against the API server's list of authenticated and open sessions
3. if TRUE then serve REST
4. if FALSE return a failed code, upon which the user needs to submit authentication creds in the digest format to authenticate, then his session begins

I just don't want to have to reauthenticate every time.

My questions are:

1. Why is REST so adamant on not mantaining any session data, which requires repeated authentication?
2. Can Jersey/Glassfish be easily modified to accommodate my deviation from the spec?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it is a problem to do "repeated authentication"? Do you have a concern that the user might have to enter credentials more than once (it is not the case)? Or that the server would have to do more processing (this is debatable and depends on the authentication scheme). What you describe is not that far away from OAuth, which uses authentication tokens (which can expire). But in general, and to answer your first question, having sessions will raise questions as soon as you have more than one app server (scalability, availability, hot deployment, etc.).

Comment: I don't think it is accurate to call this aspect of REST architecture "dogmatic" since it is part and parcel of its definition! If you create an architecture style "X" -- you can include whatever you want in that definition and then you are free to reasonably say things are "not X" when they don't meet that definition...

Comment: @OlivierLiechti, I simply don't want to do any more on the server side than look into an in-memory hashtable whether there is an authenticated sessionID.  most certainly, i do not want to check the credentials against the DB.

Comment: @david -- didn't mean to cast any aspersions with my nomenclature -- by dogmatic i meant no flexibility. i like everything about REST except that one detail.  so i do not see what would be wrong about tweaking it and be flexible about it.  technology, after all, is an ever evolving phenomenon and adaptations of existing patterns is critical.  adhering to what's at hand religiously is certainly deterrent to progress.

Comment: @OlivierLiechti -- i was thinking of some lightweight session replication within the cluster.  i have to run some diagnostics whether that or repeated authentication has less performance impact

Comment: In that case, I would use EHCache (easy to use and setup, will do the cache synchronization for you).

Comment: @foampile -- I don't know why you are going on about existing and evolving patterns in technology :) There is nothing *wrong* with tweaking it like you suggest. It is just not REST then. Specs are not supposed to be flexible in this respect. And "dogmatic" does not precisely mean "inflexible" either.

Comment: we can call it REST+ ...  LOL